# AndroidManifest.xml for Espresso testing

Tags: android, android-studio, automated-tests, android-manifest, android-espresso

While running Espresso test with Android studio, I receive an exception while writing to internal storage:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyCache: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I do understand that this issue caused by lack of permissions.

My question is, do I have to create additional AndroidManifest file for Espresso test or should I use an existing AndroidManifest file from the app itself?
I've tried the 2nd option, but it seems that MainActivityTest is not visible by my app's AndroidManifest.xml

Please refer to attached print screen:

[image: project print screen]

Comment: Which context are you using while writing to internal storage?

Comment: I am running on MainActivityTest which is my Espresso Test application

Comment: It is possible to access application under test (AUT) context by `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`. So if you have declared needed permission in your AUT then you can use it's context. Other possibility is to save your cache file inside AUT or test application package storage - data/data/com.your.package/files/cache_file. Then you don't need a permission at all.

Comment: @denys storing data at application directory worked well for me,  thank you!

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer, you can approve it. I like bounty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to access application under test (AUT) context by `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`. So if you have declared needed permission in your AUT then you can use it's context.

Other possibility is to save your cache file inside AUT or test application package storage - `data/data/com.your.package/files/cache_file`. Then you don't need a permission at all.

Answer (score 1):

could not understand your question. If your target sdk is marshmallow (sdk 24) so you have to define runtime permissions. Check this out https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Another solution would be to downgrade the target sdk (try to do this in your build.gradle) or create a new project with target = 23

Share some code so that we could understand the reason of the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should already have that permission defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. If you are running on M+ you might be looking for something similar to this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
            "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                    + " android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
}
```

this will grant you the appropriate permission for external storage access